# How to change the field value of a specific feature in a Shapefile using GDAL/OGR?

Tags: gdal, fields-attributes, ogr, features

I am trying to change the field value of a shapefile, but only in some specific features. However the code I have changes the value for all features in the shapefile. Is there any way of accessing the desired feature(s) in a simple way? This is what I have so far:

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
file = '/home/src.shp'
dataSource = driver.Open(file, 1)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
los = 1

while feature:
    feature.SetField("LOS", los)
    layer.SetFeature(feature)
    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()

dataSource.Destroy()
```

Comment: what is you criteria for choosing which features to change?

Comment: I know the ID of the feature I want to change

Comment: there is nothing in your code to make use of the ID

Comment: I don't know how to access the ID

Comment: You might like the Python ogr cookbook, https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. You can get a specific feature by passing its ID to the `layer.GetFeature(id)` method. Assuming you know the ID of the feature, you have to update your code like this:

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
file = '/home/src.shp'
dataSource = driver.Open(file, 1)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
los = 1
feat_id = 24  # change this for the actual ID

feature = layer.GetFeature(feat_id)
feature.SetField("LOS", los)
layer.SetFeature(feature)

dataSource.Destroy()
```

Remember that ID's start at 0. So the ID of the last feature of your layer would be `layer.GetFeatureCount() - 1`.